# Prove a divergent sequence exists

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Show that a positive sequence {$a_i$} exists (or does not exist) such that both of the following are true:

1. $\lim_{i\to\infty}a_i=+\infty$
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\;\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2}{a_i}-\sqrt{n\ln(n)}=+\infty$

My thoughts: I think {$a_i$} does exist: if we "ignore" the first condition and assume $a_i$ is a constant, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\;\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2}{C}-\sqrt{n\ln(n)}=2n/C-\sqrt{n\ln(n)}=+\infty$. I figured if we can make $a_i$ increase really slow, then this might work but I'm not sure. Certainly, we can try $a_i=\ln(i)$ but I don't know how to evaluate the partial sum of $1/\ln(i)$. Is there any place I can look up for lower bound of partial sums by the way? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is kind of a 1/2 baked, but you need to ensure that the difference of two intermediate sum terms $S_{n+1} - S_{n} \geq 0\; \forall n$. This will get you somethng of the form $\sum^{n+1}_{i}\frac{2}{a_i} - \sum^{n}_{i}\frac{2}{a_i} - \sqrt{(n+1) ln(n+1)} - \sqrt{n ln(n)} \geq 0$. Perhaps this would yield an expression for $a_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if we fix $0 < \beta < 1$ and define
$$  a_k = k^\beta \; ? $$
How does your question part 2. change as we try different values of $\beta?$

Easiest method for estimating a sum:

[image]

Comment: Can you be more explicit? I understand that the smaller $\beta$ is the larger the partial sum while if $\beta=0$ it's just the constant case. But $\beta$ cannot be 0 exactly. How do we know there is some fixed $\beta>0$ to make the entire thing go to positive infinity?

Comment: @DanielLi  try $\beta = \frac{1}{2}$ first. You will be able to estimate the sum... Does this value of $\beta$ finish part 2?

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a very nice trick. I tried $\beta=1/3$ and it totally worked. I didn't expect that this can be solved so neatly. Very inspiring answer.